# How do we know that a map that takes one tensor product space to another exists?

Tags: tensors

I am new to tensors and got stuck with a theorem related to Tensor contractions. It says given a map $Z$ from ordered pair of Cartesian Product to a Tensor space, we are sure that there exists another map $C$ from the Tensor Product of the same underlying vector space to the tensor product space. This is called "Universal Property".

Can anybody help me with the proof that such a map exists and what that map is?

Given, $Z: V \times V \to U$. Then, $C: V \otimes V \to U$ exists. [$\otimes$ signifies tensor product]

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You are missing details. There is **always** the zero map to any vector spze.

Comment: Yes, there's always a zero map to any vector space. But my question is related to the proof of the Universal Property Theorem. For instance, as the tensor product takes Cartesian product of vectors to real numbers (or vector space) , what map takes tensor product space to another space? I am using Ray Bowen's Introduction to Vectors and Tensors book for reference. The theorem number is 34.1.

Comment: $C(u \otimes v) := Z(u,v)$. This defines $C$ on all decomposable elements of the tensor product. This includes a basis of $V\otimes V$, so there is at most one way to extend $C$ linearly to all of $V \otimes V$. The linearity of $Z$ ensures that the result actually is linear.